# Why I am getting 404 Not Found when trying to like a product?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My goal is to allow a user to like a product and add it to the list of liked products, one user can like multiple products and each product can be liked by multiple users. But when I hit AddLike endpoint in LikeController in Postman I get 404 Not Found, however there are products with particular Id in the database. I did some coding. URL adress in postman is POST https://localhost:6001/api/like/{productId}. I have added authorization with JWT token and I have applied it correctly. Controller is called LikeController. Any suggestions?

```
//Here are product and user entity



public class Product

{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

}



public class User

{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public List<Product> LikedProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

}







    // This is my endpoint in the controller

    [HttpPost("{productId}")]

    public async Task<ActionResult> AddLike(int productId)

    {

        var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);



        var product = await _productRepository.GetProductById(id);



        var userWhoAddedProduct = await _userRepository.GetUser(product.UserId);



        if (currentUserId == userWhoAddedProduct.Id)

        {

            return BadRequest("You cannot like your own product.");

        }



        userWhoAddedProduct.LikedProducts.Add(product);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();

    }



// And here is my StoreContext

public class StoreContext : DbContext
{
    public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        if(Database.ProviderName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite")
        {
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion<double>();
                }
            }
        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOne<User>(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Products)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

    }
```

Comment: I think your issue is, the 404 is not because it cannot find your product, but it cannot find your endpoint. Without more information we cannot help you here. For example, how are you calling it in Postman? Where is your controller? What's it called?  Does it require authentication?

Comment: To prove James's suggestion, put a breakpoint on the first line of your `AddLike` method, then execute your endpoint. If you breakpoint doesn't activate, then your endpoint routing (or the URL you're providing) is incorrect.

Comment: What's the URL you are using for invoking the method? Is the `id` parameter filled in as a query parameter or does it have a JSON object in the body with a field named `id` in it?

Also, the `{ProductId}` route template parameter should match the method's `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

404 simply means, there's some issue with the Route you have defined. In order to call the Endpoint using api/like/{productId}, Please check on top of your LikeController, what route are you defining on top of it: it should be like this [Route("api/[controller]")].